# Html and css. Social buttons how to move them?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

Hey I have a problem with social buttons. I am trying to move them but only one show up on my page and I can't move that. I have three buttons and them images can someone help I am trying to put them straight line center of header or above my video.And I want to put them links.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="icons>
      <img src="facebook-64.png">
      <img src="twitter-64.png">
      <img src="instagram-64.png">
    </div>
    <img src="logo2.png">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_wrapper">
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 640px;
  top: -50px; 
}

video {
  margin-top: 250px;
}

#icons {
  top: -220px;
}
```

[image: black spot in header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using absolute positioning. Each button needs a different class. It is best practice to use classes for css styling and keep id for targeting elements with JavaScript. The images need to be wrapped in links ( tags) and the # in the href below should be set to the URL of your facebook, twitter and instagram home pages.

Personally I would set out html as:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
  <div class="icons>
    <a class="fb-link" href"#">
      <img src="facebook-64.png">
    </a>
    <a class="twr-link" href"#">
    <img src="twitter-64.png">
    </a>
    <a class="inst-link" href"#">
      <img src="instagram-64.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <img src="logo2.png">
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
```

Rather than use absolute positioning I would simply display the links as blocks and float them left. Use a margin on the containing div to position your icons. See below.

**css**

```
.icons{
  margin:20px auto; //gives margin of 20px top and bottom and centers buttons horizontally.
  width:220px;

}
.fb-link, .twr-link, .inst-link {
  display:block; 
  float:left;
  width:60px; //set width to the with of image used eg 64px
  margin-left:20px; 
}
.fb-link{
  margin-left:0; //if margin left was left at 20px the icons would be 20px off center.
}
```

Using these principles laying out the rest of you pages should be straight forward.

Comment: I see only half icon on top of my page it's stuck there.

Comment: fixed formatting of my answer so .icons shows properly and added float:left to the links.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the same style to all img tags, causing them to overlap! try changing positions for each